# iOS: button in UITableViewCell class to call method on main UIViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` on my `MainViewController` which has custom `UITableCell`s defined in a `CustomCell` class. I need an `UIButton`, which is in my `CustomCell` class, to call a method in `MainViewController`. I cannot create a new instance of `MainViewController` because the method uses some variables which would all be in the default state if I created a new instance. What do I do??

This is my code:

`MainViewController.m` (this is the method I want called):

```
-(void)updateLabels{
   double totalValue=0, personValue=0;
    [self returnTickArray];
    for(NSInteger i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        totalValue += ([[[self returnPricesArray] objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue] * [[[self returnQtyArray] objectAtIndex:i]doubleValue]);
        if([[[self returnPeopleArray] objectAtIndex:i]doubleValue]>0) personValue += ([[[self returnPricesArray] objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue] * [[[self returnQtyArray] objectAtIndex:i]doubleValue]/ [[[self returnPeopleArray] objectAtIndex:i]doubleValue] * [[[self returnTickArray] objectAtIndex:i]doubleValue]);
    }
    _totalValue.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$ %.02lf", totalValue];
    _tip.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$ %.02lf", totalValue*(([_tipPercentage.text doubleValue]/100))];
    _addedValue.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$ %.02lf",([[_tip.text substringFromIndex:2] doubleValue]+totalValue) ];
    _perPerson.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"$ %.02lf", personValue];
}
```

This is the method in `CustomCell.m` which gets called when I press the button:

```
- (IBAction)tick:(UIButton *)sender {

    if ([sender isSelected]) {
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"off"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [sender setSelected:NO];
        _isTicked = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
    }
    else {
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"on"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [sender setSelected:YES];
        _isTicked = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
    }

}
```

Comment: Add the method for the button in `MainViewController` and define *target-action* in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and you are good to go.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can assign a method from your controller to a button from UITableView in your `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`  method

```
[cell.yourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(updateLabels) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

(just don't forget to add IBOutlet of your button to your custom cell class)

Comment: *(just don't forget to add IBOutlet of your button to your custom cell class)*. Really? I don't think so. It is needed when using IB proxy objects and when you need to refer to it.

Comment: @user0000001 cell.yourButton

Answer (score 1):

Handling changes, actions, or user interaction in other views is the essential use case of [delegates](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html).  The best practice is to have the `MainViewController` be the delegate of the `CustomCell`, and then as events happen in the cell (i.e., `tick` is called), it calls certain methods on its delegate to notify it and the delegate then calls `updateLabels`.

Other options for keeping values/state in sync between views are:

- [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) - best used for data
- [Key-Value Observation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html) - best used for data
- `NSNotification`s sent through [`NSNotificationCenter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) - best used for actions

Answer (score -1):

interesting :)
You need to use `[UIApplication sharedApplication]` singleton to process this.
Here are few steps:

Create object of `MainViewController` In you `AppDelegate` class:

in `AppDelegate.h` import `MainViewController.h`

```
@interface AppDelegate
{
    MainViewController *mvc;
}
@property (strong) MainViewController *mvc;
```

in `MainViewController.m`

```
@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize mvc =_mvc
```

Now come to your `CustomCell.m`

```
- (IBAction)tick:(UIButton *)sender {

    [[(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] hvc] tick:sender];
}
```

Here you are seeing a method is called- `tick_fromCell:`. Now you have to define this method in your `MainViewController` class' `.h` ans `.m` files.

in `MainViewController.h`

```
-(void)tick:(id)sender;
```

and in `MainViewController.m`

```
-(void)tick:(id)sender {

    NSLog("Clicking from my CustomCell :)");// Here you will put updateLabels method
    [self updateLabels];
}
```